# Are enums changeable at all?

Tags: java, enums

I've been working on a game, and in the game I'm a summoner that has tamed monsters (much like pokemon).
What I want to do , is have a backpack of 5 tamed monsters, of which I can spawn 1 at a time.
Someone recommended me to use enums (I can't contact that person anymore :(), so I've been looking at a few enum tutorials and examples, and I can't figure out how this would help me.

Let us say that the enum would look like this :

```
public enum TamedMonsterStats {
    ELF(0,"res/siren_monster_girl_sprite_by_tsarcube-d52y2zu.png",0,100);
    DRAGON(0,"res/dragon.png",0,100);
    private int haveit;
    private String photoname;
    private int typeOfDamage;/* 
     * 0: dark
     * 1: light
     * 2: 
     */
    private int HP;

    TamedMonsterStats(int haveit,String photoname,int typeOfDamage,int HP){
        this.haveit = haveit;
        this.photoname = photoname;
        this.typeOfDamage = typeOfDamage;
        this.HP = HP;
    }
    public int getHaveIt(){
        return haveit;
    }
    public String getPhotoName(){
        return photoname;
    }
    public int getTypeOfDamage(){
        return typeOfDamage;
    }

    public int getHP(){
        return HP; 
    }
    public void setHp(int hp) {
        HP = hp;
    }
}
```

This would kind of work, but as daveychu pointed out, this makes it impossible for me to have 2 instances of the same creature, so my idea was to have an enum backpack with monster1,monster2,monster3,monster4,monster5 , and then filling them with the values dynamically, but I feel like doing this means I shouldn't be requiring enums at all, is this true?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a setter method on your enum:

```
public void setHp(int hp) {
    HP = hp;
}
```

However, I'm a bit wary of your use of enum. In this situation, only one "DRAGON" instance could exist at any time so I wonder what you would do if the user wants to have more of them or if the enemy has one at the same time.

Your typeOfDamage on the other hand is an excellent candidate for an enum:

```
public enum DamageType {
    DARK,
    LIGHT,
    NORMAL
}
```

You can then use this enum:

```
ELF(0, "res/siren_monster_girl_sprite_by_tsarcube-d52y2zu.png", DamageType.DARK, 100),
DRAGON(0, "res/dragon.png", DamageType.LIGHT, 100);
private DamageType typeOfDamage;

TamedMonsterStats(int haveit, String photoname, DamageType typeOfDamage, int HP) {
    this.typeOfDamage = typeOfDamage;
}

public DamageType getTypeOfDamage() {
    return typeOfDamage;
}
```

It makes it a lot more readable than having to pass some random integers.

Comment: Thank you sir, great answer! I wonder, is there any way to dynamically add monsters to the enum? Like for example , I start with 1 monster in my backpack, as I catch more and more monsters it will expand to maximum 5, is this possible? And how?

Comment: After some thinking, I believe the best way to do this is having an enum backpack with monster1,monster2,monster3,monster4,monster5 , and then filling them with the values dynamically, but I feel like doing this means I shouldn't be requiring enums at all, is this true?